# background height of selected anchor link in navigation menu

Tags: html, css, background-image

On my [website](https://akela.mendelu.cz/~xloksik/adp/doprava.html) I have blue navigation menu bar. As you can see, selected page in menu has different background img (menu-back-selected.png). My problem is that I want background img (menu-back-selected.png) height of selected link in menu in same size as whole menu bar(menu-back.png). I hope you undestand what I want :) Thx for answers

[CSS file](https://akela.mendelu.cz/~xloksik/adp/css/style.css)

Comment: Understanding what you want is easiest, when you put your code into a http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add below to `#selected {`:

```
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 7px;
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Please select the answer if you think it solves.. Also, not sure how padding-bottom:5px works because when I tried to add on you site, it was still leaving 2px space at bottom that is why I suggested 7px for bottom...

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css #selected.

padding: 5px 0;

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to give `selected` `height:100%` and `display:inline-block` and also give `main-menu` `padding:0`

The result would be

```
#selected {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    background-image: url('../images/menu-back-selected.png');
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
}
#main-menu {
   text-align:center;
   padding:0;
}
```

This solution will work regardless of the height of the `main-menu`, not hard coded like the others that could vary depending on browser